# A Spring application in a OSGI environment

Tags: java, spring, osgi, apache-servicemix

We have a spring-based application (dependency injection, persistence, transactions ...) and we are considering moving to `serviceMix`instead of our current `WSO2`

I've been doing some research to get an idea about the best practices in the context of spring+osgi, the idea is to do the migration without having to throw everything we have away, `spring-dm` seems to be a good idea, as it scans bundles containing an `ApplicationContext` and loads them, so I guess it's a solution that doesn't require a lot of work from us (please correct me if I'm wrong), it is a  dead project though so we will not use it.

So I have some questions:
Is there a way to keep our configuration files ?
Are there any good practices to do such migrations (I suppose there must be some developers who went through the same scenario) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring-dm indeed is dead. The simplest conversion should be to blueprint as it is similar to spring.

We have done a migration of a medium sized project (~50k lines) from spring to blueprint with the help of the [blueprint-maven-plugin](http://aries.apache.org/modules/blueprint-maven-plugin.html). It allows to use some of the spring as well as JEE annotations. So if the annotations you used are supported the migration should be feasible this way. For JPA there is Aries JPA which also supports the JEE annotations.

[Here you find a small example of how the end result can look like](https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/tree/master/tasklist-blueprint-cdi).

Comment: thanx for the response, so if I understand correctly, the migration would be : keeping the annotations ( if supported b the pluging) + transforming every xml based configuration into blueprint ?

Comment: Yes. If you need some more help I can give some hints.

Comment: I would love to have some advice, thank you, one last question, do you think there is a way to keep spring's configuration files and would you advise it (our codebase is big and the migration would not be an easy thing to do )

Comment: It depends a bit. In OSGi you typically have one configuration per bundle. So if your spring config files map to the bundles then you can keep them.
In any case be careful not to use the same config pid (=/etc/file) in karaf for more than one bundle. It will rather not work.

Comment: In that case, how is the ApplicationContext loaded ?

Comment: In case of blueprint you can create an xml or let the maven plugin create it. The aries blueprint bundle then scans for these contexts and automatically loads them per bundle.